How to resolve Stored/Reflected XSS for arguments passed to JS functions in a VF page?
Overview:
I am looking for ways to bypass Stored/Reflected XSS issues that are showing up as part of  CheckMarx Scan report for the arguments passed to js functions in a VF Page, given that queries in the controller class are properly sanitised with String.escapeSingleQuotes() method.
Following documentations and links are being referred:-

Secure Coding Cross Site Scripting | Secure Coding Guide | Salesforce Developers

Cross Site Scripting (XSS)

apex - How to solve Reflected XSS error in query referenced in my Visualforce Component - Salesforce Stack Exchange

visualforce - How to fix the Stored xss error in salesforce - Salesforce Stack Exchange

pmd - Apex classes should escape/sanitize Strings obtained from URL parameters: How? - Salesforce Stack Exchange


Below is the js function -
function ShowContactLookup(ctrlid,accountid,addressType,contactMethod)
{   
    lookupwindow = window.open('/apex/ContactLookUpView?usefor=Contact&AccountID='+accountid+'&ctrlid='+ctrlid+'&addressType='+addressType+'&contactMethod='+ contactMethod,'ContactCustomLookup','width=750,height=600,resizable=no,toolbar=no, menubar=no,top=100,left=300,scrollbars=yes');
} 

The following is the VF page code from where the js function is called :-
<apex:commandlink onclick="ShowContactLookup(document.getElementById('{!JSENCODE($Component.pgBlk1.pgBlk1Sec1.addtoSi.addtoAddresses)}').id, '{!JSENCODE(HTMLENCODE(accountId))}', 'ADDTO', 'Email'); return false;">{!$Label.Label_To}</apex:commandlink>                    

Solutions Tried to resolve Stored/Reflected XSS for similar intances of issues (which didn't work) :-

Tried adding JSENCODE, JSINHTMLENCODE, neither worked.
To sanitize the accountid parameter in the js function, added following custom logic :

  function escapeHTML(str) {
      return str.replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (char) {
          switch (char) {
              case '&':
                  return '&amp;';
              case '<':
                  return '&lt;';
              case '>':
                  return '&gt;';
              case '"':
                  return '&quot;';
              case "'":
                  return '&#39;';
              case '/':
                  return '&#x2F;';
              default:
                  return char;
          }
      });
  }


Implemented DOMPurify js library for HTML sanitization of the accountid parameter which was suggested in the OWASP documentation.
OWASP
Tried the encodeURIComponent method.


Move the JSENCODE into the function itself?
